# How do i select a char by mouse click event in a richTextBox and add it to a textBox1 then to textBox2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (mouseisup == false)
                {
                    int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
                    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
                    previousChar = positionToSearch;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    if (currentChar > 2 && currentChar > previousChar)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseisup = true;
        }
```

mouseisup and previousChar abd currentChar all are declared in the top of Form1.
Both previousChar abd currentChar are int and set to -1 in the top of the form1.

What i want to do is when the user click on any char/letter it will show it in the textBox1. This part is working.
Now i want to do that after the user select one char/letter and its in the textBox1 the next char/letter the user will click on will be in textBox2 and the rule should be that the next char/letter cant be the same one i mean in the same positionToSearch index and it must be more then two chars/letters far from the first one.

For example i clicked on the letter: W
And this W is in positionToSearch 432
The next char or letter i can click and select now should be any other index then 432 and should be length/far from 432 by two at least.

For example:

If in the richTextBox i have this text:

Danis is here.

I clicked on D
The next char/letter i will be able to click on to select should be n,i,s,h,e,r,e.
But i wont be able to select it wont show in textBox2 if i clicked on the same D or the next close letter/char to it in this case: a

Or for example i have this text:

Daniel is here Daniel is there.

I can select the first D and also the second D
But i cant select the first D and the first a next ot it.
Or i cant select i and then s

There must be at least two or more far selection between the selected chars/letters.

My code is not working at all.

This is what i did so far:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (mouseisup == false)
                {
                    int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
                    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
                    previousChar = positionToSearch;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    if (currentChar > previousChar + 2)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
                    }
                    currentChar = -1;
                    previousChar = -1;
                    mouseisup = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseisup = true;
        }
```

But the logic with the bool mouseisup is wrong since in the MouseUp event it will be true each time i click on a char or letter.

This is the working code as i wanted it to be with all the rules:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (mouseisup == false)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
                    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
                    previousChar = positionToSearch;
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    mouseisup = true;//add this statement
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    if (currentChar > previousChar + 2 || currentChar < previousChar - 2)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
                    }
                    mouseisup = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                mouseisup = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: First you say "This part is working." and than you say "My code is not working at all". Is at least something working, then?

Comment: I meant the part with the textBox1 is working i click on a char/letter and its adding the char/letter the mouse was on to textBox1. Now the second click is not working and should be with the rules not the same char/letter(index) and not the next char/letter to it. If i have "Daniel D" I clicked on the first D i cant select now the a next to the first D but i can select the second D. You cant select the same index and not the next char/letter.

Comment: Edited my question with what i did so far.

Comment: @DoronMuzar: so which code you are trying, in your question you have given 2 codes?

Comment: Sudhakar the last one. Its working with textBox1 but not with the rules i wanted of textBox2.

Comment: @DoronMuzar: so you need to display the first selected character in first `TextBox` and next selected character which is 2 letters far in next `TextBox` right?

Comment: Sudhakar indeed you are right and also in the textBox2 it cant be the same letter/char in the selected index of textBox1. It can be the same char/letter in other places in the text. This is the two rules you right.

Comment: @DoronMuzar: check my answer :) you need to set the `mouseisup` to true in if block.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41819/discussion-between-sudhakar-tillapudi-and-doron-muzar)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** you are not setting the `mouseisup` variable to `true` in your `if` condition block. if you don't set it to `true` you will never enter into `else` block that is the reason why you are not able to see the next selected text in `TextBox2`

**Solution :** set the `mouseisup` variable to `true` in `if block` 
as below:

```
mouseisup = true;
```

**Complete solution:**

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
   {
     if (mouseisup == false)
     {
      int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
      richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
      textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
      previousChar = positionToSearch;
      mouseisup = true;//add this statement
     }
   else
   {
     currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
     if (currentChar > previousChar + 2)
     {
       richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
       textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
     }
     currentChar = -1;
     previousChar = -1;
     mouseisup = false;
   }
  }
 }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mouseisup = true;
        }
```

Comment: Sudhakar i tried this before and also your solution now. Thep roblem is that its working on the first time but after i select the char/letter for the textBox2 i can select again any letter near it or the first letter in textBox1 . The idea is that it should be licke a block or locked area. I click on a letter/char and add it to textBox1 then do the textBox2 but if i will click now on another char/letter it should be reset everything and make the rules again but it dosent i can click on any char letter and it will replace it in textBox2.

Comment: The problem is in the MouseUp event after the first time each time it will be true since it will allywas will get to the mouseup event. So even if i set it to false in the ELSE part it will be true again since i made a click.

Comment: please join this room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41819/discussion-between-sudhakar-tillapudi-and-doron-muzar

Comment: I will edit my question with the working code as i wanted it to be with all rules.